# Transfer string to data frame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large string which I have to transfer into a data frame. For example the string is:

> meals_string = "APPETIZERS Southern Fried Quail with
>   Greens,Huckleberries,Pecans & Blue Cheese  14.00 Park Avenue Cafe
>   Chopped Salad Goat Feta Cheese,Nigoise Olives,Marinated White  [...]
>   ENTREES Horseradish Crusted Canadian Salmon,Potato Fritters, Marinated
>   Cucumbers,Chive Vinaigrette  27.00 Sautéed Prawns with Mushroom
>   Tortellini,Grilled Tomato Vinaigrette & Sweet Corn  29.50"

```
meals = meals_string.splitlines()
```

Which gives me var "meals" as list, but I am stuck how to convert the string into dataframe with 3 columns: Category; Meal_name; Price

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple parser for your string can be built and the passed directly to `pandas.DataFrame` like:

#### Code:

```
def meal_string_parser(meal_string):
    category = ''
    meal = []
    price = 0
    for word in meal_string.split():
        if word:
            try:
                price = float(word)
                yield category, ' '.join(meal), price
                meal = []
            except ValueError:
                # this is not a number, so not a price
                if word.upper() == word and word.isalnum():
                    # found category
                    category = word
                else:
                    meal.append(word)

    if meal:
        yield category, ' '.join(meal), price
```

#### Test Code:

```
meals_string = """
APPETIZERS 
    Southern Fried Quail with Greens,Huckleberries,Pecans & Blue Cheese 14.00
    Park Avenue Cafe Chopped Salad Goat Feta Cheese,Nigoise Olives,Marinated White 13.00 
ENTREES
    Horseradish Crusted Canadian Salmon,Potato Fritters, Marinated Cucumbers,Chive Vinaigrette 27.00
    Sautéed Prawns with Mushroom Tortellini,Grilled Tomato Vinaigrette & Sweet Corn 29.50
"""

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(meal_string_parser(meals_string),
                  columns='Category Meal_name Price'.split())
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
     Category                                          Meal_name  Price
0  APPETIZERS  Southern Fried Quail with Greens,Huckleberries...   14.0
1  APPETIZERS  Park Avenue Cafe Chopped Salad Goat Feta Chees...   13.0
2     ENTREES  Horseradish Crusted Canadian Salmon,Potato Fri...   27.0
3     ENTREES  Sautéed Prawns with Mushroom Tortellini,Grille...   29.5
```